# Hard drive not visible during Linux Mint installation

Tags: hard-drive, installation, block-device, linuxmint

I had successfully installed Linux Mint 19 on my new Dell laptop at work. It was working fine, in general, though it did not shut down properly. I'd seen somewhere a video driver might be responsible, so I used the Driver Manager to switch from Noveau to an Nvidia driver. I hit the "Reset" button on Driver Manager. Again, the machine did not shut down, so I held down the power button.

After that, Mint would not boot. I tried a number of things, to no avail. So I thought I'd just reinstall, since there wasn't much on the machine.

The machine has an SSD and a bigger HD. When I run the Mint installer from a live USB, I only see the SSD during the disk partitioning step (/dev/sda). Both fdisk and parted, run from the command line, only report /dev/sda. I'm supposing the HD should appear as /dev/sdb.

Is there a reason why the HD does not appear? Can I make it appear, so it can be used during the installation? Or is the behavior I see expected?

Comment: Does the BIOS detect the hard drive?

Comment: Yes, I see both disks in the BIOS setup.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear. In the BIOS "Device Information", it shows M.2.PCIe SSD-0, with a serial number. For M.2 SATA, it says "None."

Comment: While in the System Configuration/Drives, it shows the SSD drive, and SATA-1 and SATA-2.

Comment: Well, I found a way to boot the machine again (turning off RAID in the BIOS). So I don't need to reinstall, so this issue is mooted for me.